# ASP.Net Regular Expression Validation of String Length

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to validate if the string entered by user into a text box is at least 3 characters long. I was using following regex:

```
\w{3,40}
```

But it fails if user enters say:

```
my valid string
```

I want something that will validate the total string length including spaces between the words but not at end or beginning of the string.

So following are valid:

```
"a    bc"
"a  b  c"
"abc"
"a b c"
```

but following are not:

```
"a b   "
"  a      "
"    bc"
```

NOTE:- It is to be done on client side as any changes to server side code will require restarting site which I don't want to do.

Comment: Do you really need it in regex?

Comment: Well @coder there is a RegularExpression Validator on page already. I have make it work using normal JS though. But thought of quickly closing it with working `regex`. Just waiting to see if we can build a reged. Seems we need to play with groups and I am not very well versed in that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Call [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) method in the input and try to use this as your regex pattern:

```
[\w\s]{3,40}
```

`\s` will matches all whitespaces characters.

I test it in [here](http://regexpal.com/)

More: [Regular Expression Basic Syntax Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: How can you call `trim` in a regular-expression validator?

Comment: well sure can call from ASP.Net code but this is to be done on client side. Otherwise it will not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are just having fun with regular expressions but the following check should work:

```
if ( s.Trim().Length >= 3 ) 
{
    // do awesome stuff here that you would never do with some other crazy string
}
```

Comment: Well this is the sure-shot way but it is an already running application and have to update this thing only in a regex validator. Don't want to mess up anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I am still waiting for the working regex. I have tried following, but it fails if there is a space at end of the string:

```
^[\S|\S\s]{2,40}\S$
```

Meanwhile I am using following approach to passon custom validation function:

```
function pageLoad() {
    var val = document.all ? document.all["<%=control.ClientID%>"] : 
                            document.getElementById("<%=control.ClientID%>");
    if (val) {
        val.evaluationfunction = function () {
            try {
                var v = ValidatorGetValue(val.controltovalidate); 
                v = ValidatorTrim(v); 
                return v.length >= 3;
            } catch (err) {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Note that most of it is picked from Microsoft ASP.Net Javascript Validation library itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works...

Note: Not tested

**`[A-Za-z]{3}([A-Za-z]+ ?)*`**

Comment: :) well you have almost nailed it but it will fail if someone enters digit or some other character like 'T2013` which is otherwise valid input.